# How to extract words from a string beginning at the end of the string?

Tags: r, string

NOTE: The previous question was reformulated for the actual one.

```r
# **Previous question:**

# How to extract words from a string beginning from the end of the string? 

str1 <- "then you must be in fact a wonderful kid"

# Desired answer for each command:

# "kid"
# "wonderful kid"                      
# "a wonderful kid"
# "fact a wonderful kid"
```

**Reformulated question:**

Being more specific:

How to extract the last 4 words from an unkown string?

Comment: you can tokenise your string using `unlist(stri_split_fixed("then you must be in fact a wonderful kid", ' '))` then extract the number of words you need, that could be a start. It's a bit hard to understand your selection criteria thorugh

Answer (score 3):

With `stringr`, we can use `word` with arguments `start = -4` and `end = -1` to extract the four last words of the sentence:

```r
str1 <- "then you must be in fact a wonderful kid"

stringr::word(str1, start = -4, end = -1)
#> [1] "fact a wonderful kid"
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use the vectorized `substring` with `rev` as follows:

```
 rev(substring(str1,gregexpr("(?<= )",str1,perl=TRUE)[[1]],nchar(str1)))
[1] "kid"                                 "wonderful kid"                      
[3] "a wonderful kid"                     "fact a wonderful kid"               
[5] "in fact a wonderful kid"             "be in fact a wonderful kid"         
[7] "must be in fact a wonderful kid"     "you must be in fact a wonderful kid"
```

NOTE: CHANGING YOUR QUESTION FROM WHAT IT WAS ORIGINALLY MAKES THIS ANSWER OBSOLETE. THE QUESTION HERE IS COMPLETELY DIFFERENT FROM WHAT IT WAS. YOU SHOULD OTHERWISE CONSIDER ASKING A DIFFERENT QUESTION EACH TIME AND NOT TO CHANGE THE ORIGINAL QUESTION.

Comment: Perfect @Onyambu, sorry for my mistake. The previous question didn't met what i need, an I inadvertently changed the question (i'm new here). Once others have answered the new question, i've registered both questions in the description. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` *to extract the last 4 words from a string* like:

```
str1 <- "then you must be in fact a wonderful kid"
sub(".*(( *\\b\\w+){4})$", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "fact a wonderful kid"
```

which will also work in case the string has less than 4 words.

```
str1 <- "then you must"
sub(".*(( *\\b\\w+){4})$", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "then you must"
```